# Not able to start hivemq server on a remote server?

Tags: websocket, mqtt, hivemq

I have made two servers one is dummy test server and other is where my django project is running. I am able to run hivemq server on my dummy server but it is throwing a error while i try to run it on my project server.

```
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
at org.jgroups.logging.LogFactory.getLog(Unknown Source)
at org.jgroups.blocks.MessageDispatcher.<init>(Unknown Source)
at b.a.a(Unknown Source)
at com.hivemq.HiveMQEnterpriseServer.b(Unknown Source)
at com.hivemq.HiveMQEnterpriseServer.a(Unknown Source)
at com.hivemq.HiveMQEnterpriseServer.main(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at java.base/java.util.Locale.<init>(Locale.java:713)
at java.base/java.util.Locale.<init>(Locale.java:742)
at org.jgroups.logging.Slf4jLogImpl.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
... 6 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 5):

This error is thrown by jGroups which expects from the system in which it is running that the environment variable LOCALE is set.

By adding LOCALE with the value "C.UTF-8" to the environment variables you can fix this easily.

Best regards,

Abdullah from The HiveMQ Team

Comment: This issue was fixed in HiveMQ 4.0.2. Could you try it again with the latest HiveMQ version (4.2.0)?

Comment: yes i have upgraded it already, you guys should notify the users.